# Advantages of explicitly writing an index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I wonder why one should ever care on explicitly writing an index in query. I frequently see queries like this

```
select blabla from Table with(nolock index = index_name)
```

Index is already defined, and query optimizer chooses the best index by itself. Isn't it more logical and efficient to write query as this:

```
select blabla from Table with(nolock)
```

What are the advantages of explicitly writing an index in query?

**EDIT**
Thank you all for your opinions. The best choice is not to force seeking indexes explicitly. 
In this case only database vendors could be advantageous and it is not related with performance. They indicate indexes explicitly and force execution plan to not to change in order to be able to predict execution times.

Comment: Slightly off topic but always worth highlighting; although NOLOCK can reduce query execution times it comes at a cost.  This query hint can return data that has been [deleted, changed or was never committed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173763.aspx).

Comment: It's generally considered not to be a good idea. Because there is usually some other underlying reason the index isn't used and that should be fixed. Also as data changes, at a later time this index may be unsuitable but it has been forced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is question is kind of rhetoric: one must measure efficiency, not reason about it.

In ssms you can do it with "Include Actual Execution Plan" (Ctrl-M).

Try execute following in ssms and look at "Execution plan":

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs with (index = nc1)

SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs with (index = clust)

SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
```

You will find that: a)first index hint is only slowing, b) hint on clustered index and no hint have equivalent plans

Answer (score 1):

Specifying Index in the SQL SERVER causes Force Seeking of that Index.

> When any query is ran SQL Server Engine determines which index has to
>   be used. SQL Server makes uses Index which has lowest cost based on
>   performance. Index which is the best for performance is automatically
>   used. There are some instances when Database Developer is best judge
>   of the index used. DBA can direct SQL Server which index to be used to
>   execute query.
>
> If the index that you have created is not picked up by SQL Server,
>   then try telling the SQL Server by using the HINT.

you can refer below links

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/07/sql-server-introduction-to-force-index-query-hints-index-hint/

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/index-selection-and-the-query-optimizer/

Comment: Yes, but why one should force seeking index? Optimizer do this job better.  Sources say that in some special circumstances using Force Seeking if Index is preferable. What are those special cases?

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be useful in case when sql engine creates execution plan for queries in stored procedure. It maybe situation when SQL engine created execution plan for parameters that passed in stored procedure first (parameters sniffing). For that values SQL engine can take decision not to use index. So to avoid it you can explicit set index usage.

Additional information about parameter sniffing you can find in this article (http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options) and here (http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)